# Find possible pairs from binary string

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an array of strings with values only 0 and 1.

Example:
["100" , "110", "010", "011", "100"]

Now I want to take each string and compare it with all other strings and see how many of them differ by 1. For example:

"100" compared with "110", the element at each index is checked, if they are different by a maximum of 1 position then they are considered similar. So for String "100" in above array, the similar elements are "110" and "100".

My program returns an array of integers where each value indicates the number of similar strings at that index in list.

Example:

Input :

["100" , "110", "010", "011", "100"]

Output:
[2,3,2,1,2]

Explanation:
At index 1, input is "110" the similar strings are 3 which are "100", "010", "100".

Here is my code:

```
static List<Integer> process(String[] input) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
            if (i != j) {
                int differ = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < input[i].length(); k++) {
                    if (input[i].charAt(k) != input[j].charAt(k)) {
                        differ++;
                    }
                    if (differ > 1) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (differ <= 1) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        list.add(count);
    }
    return list;
}
```

How can I improve the time complexity of this code?

All Strings are of the same length and the length ranges from 1 to 20. Size of input array is up to 10,000.

Comment: You missed few details: are all the strings of same length (I guess so)? What is the max length of the strings?

Comment: @NiVeR, I have added that now.

Answer (score 3):

We can exploit the fact that all input strings are of the same length to build a simple binary radix tree over the characters 0 and 1, and store the count of matching strings in the leaves.

You can then use a recursive function to navigate the tree for each input string, considering at most one divergence, where you visit the child with the opposite character. You sum all the leaf nodes reached in this manner.

First we build the tree:

```
static class Node 
{
    Node[] child = new Node[2];
    int count;
}

static Node buildTree(String[] s)
{
    Node root = new Node();
    for(String bs : s)
    {
        Node node = root;
        for(char c : bs.toCharArray())
        {
            int i = c - '0';
            if(node.child[i] == null) 
                node.child[i] = new Node();
            node = node.child[i];
        }
        node.count++;
    }
    return root;
}
```

Then we use recursion to count matching strings. Note that if we reach the leaf and `diff` is 0, i.e. we've located the original string, then we need to reduce the count by 1, as we're not counting self-matches.

```
static int countDiff(Node node, String s, int pos, int diff)
{
    if(pos == s.length()) 
        return diff == 0 ? node.count-1 : node.count;

    int i = s.charAt(pos) - '0';

    int sum = 0;
    if(diff == 0 && node.child[(i+1)%2] != null)
        sum += countDiff(node.child[(i+1)%2], s, pos+1, 1);
            
    if(node.child[i] != null)
        sum += countDiff(node.child[i], s, pos+1, diff);
    
    return sum;     
}
```

Test:

```
String[] s = {"100" , "110", "010", "011", "100"};

Node root = buildTree(s);

int[] count = new int[s.length];
for(int i=0; i<s.length; i++)
    count[i] = countDiff(root, s[i], 0, 0);
    
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(count));
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 2, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

I really like [RaffleBuffle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68274462) which uses radix trees.

But just as a faster-to-implement alternative — you might instead use `int[]` as a frequency map: index `i` stores how many copies of number `i` are in `input`.
The size of the frequency map array depends on the width of input strings — so it's up to `int[220] == int[1'048'576]`.

```java
  static List<Integer> process(String[] input) {
    var bitWidth = input[0].length();
    var values = new int[input.length];
    var freqMap = new int[1 << bitWidth]; // 2^bitWidth;
    
    // fill values and frequency map
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      var value = toInt(input[i]);
      values[i] = value;
      freqMap[value]++;
    }
    
    var result = new ArrayList<Integer>(values.length);
    // fill results
    for (var value : values) {
      var numClose = freqMap[value] - 1;
      // close value: one bit flipped
      for (var iBit = 0; iBit < bitWidth; iBit++) {
        var closeVal = flipBit(value, iBit);
        numClose += freqMap[closeVal];
      }
      result.add(numClose);
    }
    return result;
  }
  
  private static int toInt(String inputValue) {
    var result = 0;
    for (int pos = inputValue.length() - 1, posWeight = 1; pos >= 0; pos--, posWeight <<= 1) {
      if (inputValue.charAt(pos) == '1') {
        result += posWeight;
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
  
  private static int flipBit(int value, int bitPosition) {
    return value ^ (1 << bitPosition);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

A Frankenstein answer combined from:

- using `Set` (actually `HashMap` to support repeating input numbers) as in [talex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68273209)
- using `Integer.valueOf(String, 2)` to convert input to `int` numbers as in [GURU Shreyansh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68273068)
- using bit fliping to compute close values as in [user16394029's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68276541)

The code we get:

```java
  static List<Integer> process(String[] input) {
    var values = new ArrayList<Integer>(input.length);
    var freqMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(input.length);
    var bitWidth = input[0].length();

    for (var inputValue : input) {
      var value = Integer.parseInt(inputValue, 2);
      values.add(value);
      freqMap.compute(value, (key, old) -> (old == null) ? 1 : (old + 1));
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
      var value = values.get(i);
      var numClose = freqMap.get(value) - 1;
      for (var iBit = 0; iBit < bitWidth; iBit++) {
        numClose += freqMap.getOrDefault(flipBit(value, iBit), 0);
      }
      values.set(i, numClose);
    }
    return values;
  }

  private static int flipBit(int value, int bitPosition) {
    return value ^ (1 << bitPosition);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use set.

1. Put all strings in set `s`
2. For each string generate all string that differs by single change
3. Count number of generated strings that belong to `s`

It will have complexity of `O(n*m*m)` instead of `O(n*n*m)` your algorithm have.
`n` is number of strings and `m` is length of string.

So it is better in regards of `n`, but worse in regards of `m`.

Also it requires `O(n*m)` memory. Original algorithm requires `O(max(log(n), log(m)))` memory.

For better performance convert strings to integers.

Comment: My bad, I assumed a pair should be counted once, you have my +1

Comment: It will take `O(m*m)` to generate all sting that differ in one position from string of length `m`. There is error in my analysis. It should be `O(n*m*m)`, not  `O(n*m)`. I'll fix my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I can suggest an `O(N^2)` approach using `bitwise XOR`. The result of XOR is 1 if the two bits are different. So, we can use this property to find the count of positions where the bit are different.

```java
    int[] num = new int[input.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
        num[i] = Integer.valueOf(input[i], 2); // converting to integral form
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < input.length; j++)
        {
            if (i == j) // skip
                continue;
            if (Integer.bitCount(num[i] ^ num[j]) <= 1) // similar
            {
                ++count;
            }
        }
        list.add(count);
    }
```

I've used `bitCount` method of `java.lang package` which returns the count of the number of one-bits in the two's complement binary representation of a number to find the set bits in the resultant `XOR`. Number of set bits in the resultant `XOR` indicates that that many positions were different between the two numbers.

Comment: It is `O(1)`. For input of limited size (it doesn't work for unlimited sizes). So we can go two way from here: take into account that `M` is limited by `20`, but then we have to adjust my initial analysis (which was done without constraints) It will mean that original algorithm is O(N*N). Or we can extrapolate algorithm used in `bitCount` to work with unlimited input, which will mean that it is no longer `O(1)`.